# checking All checkbox asp.net jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am using asp.net c# jquery vs 2008

I have two check box list (cbList,checkboxList1) and one check box (chkALL).
when i checked the check box(chkALL),it should check all checkboxes in Check box list(CbList)

I am using the following code in jquery.It is not working properly.It checks both checkbox list.I need to check only one checkboxlist. Any help appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">


               function jqCheckAll2(id, name) {

                   $("INPUT[@Name=" + name + "][type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#' + id).is(':checked'));

               }






       </script>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Check All" onclick="jqCheckAll2( this.id, 'cbList' )"/><br />


    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not see exactly what is causing your problem, but what I can see is that you are using `cbList` as the name which is a server side name. Instead you should use `cbList.ClientID` which is a unique client side name for the control. In other words add the `onclick` event side like this:

```
chkAll.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("jqCheckAll2(this.id, '{0}')", cbList.ClientID);
```

then change jqCheckAll2 to this:

```
       function jqCheckAll2(id, name) {
           $("#" + name).find(":checkbox").attr('checked', $('#' + id).is(':checked'));
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the checkbox to check all or uncheck all for all the active checkbox inside a div.   ClientIDMode="Static" just doesn't allow the ID change when running on server.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
    <asp:Label ID="lblAll" runat="server" Text="Label" ClientIDMode="Static">Select All</asp:Label>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#chkAll").on('change', function() { // on change of state        
            if (this.checked) // if changed state is "CHECKED"
            {
                $("#lblAll").text("Unselect All");
                $("#myDiv input[type=checkbox]").each(
                    function() {
                        if($(this).attr('disabled')==null)
                          $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                $("#lblAll").text("Select All");
                $("#myDiv input[type=checkbox]").each(
                    function () {
                        if ($(this).attr('disabled') == null)
                           $(this).prop('checked', false);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    });
```